# Method name conventions for setters and getters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

I want all my instance variables private and accessors/mutators in public methods. I am wondering if there is a naming convention that I should be aware of when building large classes, a convention both for readability among other developers, but also a convention that prevents method name clashing with other classes.

For example, if I want a class to access and change a "quality" (not necessarily a specific variable) called "supports musicians," would `[myInstance setSupportsMusicians:YES]` and `[myInstance returnSupportsMusicians]` be acceptable names,  using `set` and `return` as method name prefixes for all other mutators and accessors?

Obviously I know I can name them anything I want, but I wanted to get some opinions since I know naming conventions are a significant component of organized development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be best off using `@property` to declare things like this.  That way you can get all its implementation benefits (like atominicity, automatic ivar generation, etc) along with convenient dot syntax (e.g. `myInstance.supportsMusicians = YES`), all without having to worry about the underlying method names at all.

But in case you do want to declare your methods manually, or just want to know what the auto-generated ones are, the naming convention is:

```
- (void)setSupportsMusicians:(BOOL)supportsMusicians;
- (BOOL)supportsMusicians;
```

There's also a side-case for some types of booleans properties, where "is" is used as a prefix for readability, e.g.

```
- (BOOL)isVisible;
```

This is not followed universally, however, and might be considered a legacy convention.

Note that "get" as a prefix shouldn't be used randomly as it has a specific meaning:  it's used in a context where the caller provides a buffer to be filled in, e.g. `-[NSString getBytes:length:]`.

Answer (score 2):

set and get are Java & few other language style.

But cocoa style is as (Pseudocode, for names):

setName() in cocoa is setName:

getName() in cocoa is name:

EDIT: this is only for naming convention, dont take it as a syntax for methods.

Few helpful links  :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct "cocoa style" since the parenthesis suggest you are talking about functions, not methods. I am referring to object methods in Objective-C, not C-style function conventions

Comment: You might want to just use @proprty and @synthesize (overriding only when necessary), instead of writing all the setters/getters yourself. You'll then be able to use `myInstance.supportsMusicians` notation to read/write to the variable (it's still using the getter/setters behind the scenes).

Comment: for getters/setter @property is enough, newer xcode creates a hidden synthesize. For all other private or public methods use same kind of style, no "get" or "return" be used.

Comment: @Kitsune for full encapsulation you can use a `private` form `@property` outside the header file (in implementation) to still get the benefits of memory management with properties, but still use only public methods for setters/getters.

Comment: good links. looks like "get" is actually not suggested, according to the documents.